How to show a permutation in a disjoint cycles?
I have a permutation (12)(345)(18)(567)(12) and the answer should be (related to Wolfram)
(28)(34675)(1)
When going the numbers through I'm having trouble with the 4. Isn't it right that from right to left the 4 is send to 5. And similar: 5 send to 6.
My answer is (28)(34567)(1). What's going wrong?

You are multiplying right to left, Wolfram is multiplying left to right.

Is my answer right?

Only if you're supposed to multiply right to left!

Your answer is correct. (I am considering that you're multiplying from right to left)
Ask if you have any other questions.
Hope this helps.
